# I am working on a dark mode preferences. Windows application

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a dark mode toggle for my windows application built-in node js and electron GUI. The problem is that I can toggle the dark mode on a page and it is perfect but as you soon as navigating to another page it reverts to light mode. I was wondering if it would be possible to save a darkmode = true in a preferences file or something.

```js
INDEX.js

function darkMode(){
    var element = document.body;
    element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
    document.cookie = "dark=True";
    var dark = True
    console.log(dark)
}
```

```css
STYLES.CSS

body {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}

.dark-mode {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
SETTING.HTML

<button onclick="window.location='index.html', id='homeBTN'">Home</button>


<script type = "text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
<button onclick="darkMode()">Toggle Dark Mode</button>

INDEX.HTML

<script type = "text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>

<body>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
localStorage.setItem("darkMode", "true"); // or false
```

Then later you will want to read it back, but you need to parse the data back.

```
let isDarkMode =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("darkMode"));
```

isDarkMode will be your value you check on all subsequent pages.

By the way, if you want to write out your boolean type to localStorage you have to stringify it.  Values stored in localStorage are strings (which is also why you have to call JSON.parse() on the value when reading it back in.

```
localStorage.setItem("darkMode", JSON.stringify(isDarkMode));
```

Answer (score 0):

I will do that with setting `:root` css variables and `.dark` class to body

CSS

```
:root {
--background: white;
--color: black
}

.dark {
--background: black;
--color: white;
}

body {
background: var(--background);
color: var(--color);
}
```

And then with JavaScript you can toggle class dark to the body

```
const handleDarkTheme = () => {
document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
}
```

HTML

```
<button onclick="handleDarkTheme()">Toggle Dark Mode</button>
```

But that will return to light on every app refresh or re-run. Best way will be to use some sort of JSON local file with settings and than fetch that with javascript on every run.